# Kivy autofit (autoresize) image to screen

Tags: image, screen, kivy, autoresize, normalize

we are developing a kivy mobile app that uses an image as the banner at the top of the screen (the rest of the screen consists of buttons and text within a GridLayout). Currently, we have been able to use "size_hint" to make sure each of the children are appropriately scaled on my samsung S4. However, whenever we run the app in the Kivy window (or on any other phone) the banner does not fit the screen correctly. How can we go about fixing this problem? We have tried using "allow_stretch" and "keep_ratio" and although they work, they inappropriately scale the image. Our hypothesis is that we should use "norm_image_size" but can't find any examples of how to use it so that the banner normalizes correctly on all screens.

Is "norm_image_size" the right method to use in this instance?
If so, can someone point us to an example of how to use it correctly?

Thanks

Below is the code in our kv file. As I said above, I can use the "size_hint" in each child of the BoxLayout to make them all scale correctly on my phone, but this scaling does not hold true in the Kivy window on my mac.

```
Screen:
    name: 'screen1'
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    AnchorLayout:               
        anchor_y: 'top'
        anchor_x: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size: self.width, self.height
            GridLayout:
                canvas:
                    Rectangle:
                        source: 'img/banner1.png'
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                cols: 5
                spacing: '20dp'
                padding: '12dp'
                row_default_height: '50dp'
                row_force_default: True
                size_hint: (1.0,.1)
                Image:
                    source: 'img/logo1.png'
                Image:
                Image:
                Image:
                Image:
            GridLayout:
                row_default_height: '80dp'
                row_force_default: True
                cols: 5
                spacing: '5dp'
                padding: '10dp'
                size_hint: (1,.7)
                Button:
                    id: square1
                Button:
                    id: square2
                Button:
                    id: square3
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square4
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square5
                    text:
                Button:
                    id: square6
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square7
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square8
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square9
                    text:
                Button:
                    id: square10
                Button:
                    id: square11
                Button:
                    id: square12
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square13
                Button:
                    id: square14
                    text:
                Button:
                    id: square15
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square16
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square17
                    text: 
                Button:
                    id: square18
                    text:
                Button:
                    id: square19
                    text:
                Button:
                    id: square20
                    text:
            GridLayout:
                row_default_height: '50dp'
                row_force_default: True
                cols: 1
                size_hint: (1,.07)
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1,1,1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'Return Home'
                    font_size: '12sp'
                    font_name: 'fonts/text1.ttf'
                    background_normal: 'img/return_home4.png'
                    background_down: 'img/return_home4.png'
                    border: 20,20,20,20
                    on_press: root.current = 'home'
```

Comment: According to the documentation, norm_image_size is read-only, so that's probably not the solution. To me, this sounds like a layout issue rather than an issue with the image. Is the image inside the same GridLayout as the buttons and labels? Should the height remain the same but width change, or should they both scale? A working code example where the issue is present would always be very helpful.

Comment: I'll second what NotNone said. If the space for the banner is the wrong shape to contain it, how do you expect things to work *except* by leaving some blank space or changing the image aspect ratio?

Comment: thanks for the help. I've pasted in our kv code above. Let me know what you think

Comment: Everything looks good on my PC if I add `allow_stretch: True` and `keep_ratio: False` to the banner image. Everything is scaling as it should. You can also remove the size-property inside BoxLayout as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: As another note, if at all possible, I like to use only one root widget inside a Screen. Here, `FloatLayout` could be the only child of the screen. Then, as a child of the `FloatLayout`, add a `GridLayout` with `cols: 1` and add the `Image` and `GridLayout`s inside it. Makes the code a bit more compact and coherent.

Comment: Thanks NotNone. One quick follow-up question, is there anyway to keep the aspect ratio but also have the image scale to different screen sizes? Our image has a logo that looks distorted when the image stretches. Alternatively, what's the best practice for putting a logo on an image and then having scale according to screen size? For example, is it possible to overlay one image on top of another and have only the image in the background stretch as necessary?

Comment: As quick follow-up, we figured out how to make the banner look good on all screens by replacing the image with a GridLayout, using the background of the previous image as the source for the canvas, and then inserting the logo as a child of the GridLayout (see updated code above). NotNone, is this best practice or do you recommend another approach? Also, I tried to use only one root widget inside the Screen as you suggested but couldn't get the last button to sit at the bottom of the screen. Any suggestions on how to deal with that issue? For now, I've kept multiple children underneath Screen